# How to send Email from Oracle form

Tags: oracle, email

I want to automatically send a report by email through Oracle Forms 11g.  I have achieved to make the report run automatically but at the same time i want the PDF to be attached and sent in email. I found and tried this code but didn't work. Can anyone help me please?

```
DECLARE

report_id REPORT_OBJECT := find_report_object('checklist'); 
report_message VARCHAR2(100) :=''; 
rep_status VARCHAR2(100) :=''; 
v_error Exception; 
thelist paramlist; 

BEGIN 


thelist:= Get_Parameter_List('rep_paramlist');
If NOT Id_Null (thelist) THEN
DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST(thelist);
end if;
thelist := Create_Parameter_List ('rep_paramlist'); 

ADD_PARAMETER(thelist, 'FROM',TEXT_PARAMETER, 'shl@gmail.com');
ADD_PARAMETER(thelist, 'SUBJECT',TEXT_PARAMETER, 'Report Attached'); 
ADD_PARAMETER(thelist, 'PROJECT_NBR',TEXT_PARAMETER, 968404);


SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_COMM_MODE, SYNCHRONOUS); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_FILENAME, 'NEW.RDF'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_SERVER, 'rep_calamity'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESTYPE, MAIL ); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESFORMAT, 'PDF'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(report_id,REPORT_DESNAME,'sm@gmail.com' ); 


report_message := run_report_object (report_id, thelist); 
rep_status := report_object_status (report_message); 


begin

WHILE rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED')
LOOP
rep_status := report_object_status(report_message); 
END LOOP; 
exception 
when v_error then 
message('Error in sending Action Checklist email.'|| rep_status); 
end;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Has any mail configuration (allowing mail generated using this method to be relayed/transported through your network)?

Comment: Actually I'm not allowed to make any changes in the server. I want to send email as soon as my report open. How to do that.